# deleting row from database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Why this code is not deleting row and show error message

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("DELETE  from [course] where cid ('"+cids.Text+"')",con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("done.aspx");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        { Label1.Text = "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error message is it showing? (Hint: change `catch(SqlException)` to `catch(SqlException e)` and post the value of `e`)

Comment: I suspect your SQL is a little rusty. Perhaps you should consult the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to use `=`

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("DELETE  from [course] where cid ('"+cids.Text+"')",con);
```

This line shoud be

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("DELETE  from [course] where cid ='"+cids.Text+"'",con);
```

or use `WHERE cid IN (...)`

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("DELETE  from [course] where cid IN ('"+cids.Text+"')",con);
```

---

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("DELETE  from [course] where cid IN ('"+cids.Text+"')",con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("done.aspx");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        { 
         Label1.Text = "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain

Comment: it does not delete row from database but control goes to next page

Answer (score 4):

**USE SQL PARAMETERS, YOUR CODE IS TOTALLY UNSAFE, FIX IT!**

Did you mean to use the SQL IN clause? That would be "WHERE cid IN (...)", or just single value with "WHERE cid = ..."

See [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause/337792#337792) to use parameters with IN clause

Comment: now using this SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE  from [course] where cid IN ('" + cids.Text + "')", con);

Comment: @user3359284 the point TFD is making is that _any_ query you build strictly by creating a string has the potential to cause problems, including the potential to have very unwanted queries injected into your database through this insecure hole you create. Imagine for example that `cids.Text` is `"); drop table course"`... your query is not likely to please you! Using **proper** parameterized query creation avoids this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("DELETE  from [course] where cid ('"+cids.Text+"')",con);
```

Should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("DELETE  from [course] where cid IN ('"+cids.Text+"')",con);
```

Notice the "in" between cid and (

The assumption is that you should use `in` because of the parens.  But if you have only one value you are wanting to compare to then `=` should do the trick.

Also, as @TFD notes, you should use parameterized SQL.  This code will allow for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: now moves to the next page but does not delete row from database

Comment: @user3359284  What error are you getting?

Comment: does delete row from database but moves to next page

Comment: I dont understand.  Now it DOES delete the row?  What is the value of `SqlException`?

Comment: @user3359284 Please change `catch(SqlException)` to `catch(SqlException e)` and post the value of `e`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, did you ever read the SQL syntax somewhere? Or are you just throwing random stuff at a wall and hoping it sticks?

```
cid ('"+cids.Text+"')",
```

Let's ignore the fact that this is the best way to get fired - anyone can execute ANY RANDOM SQL HE WANTS in your database. Bad news - happens when you do not check your input (cids.Text.

But brutally sppeaking, if I have 55 in the text box, that translates into:

```
cid ('55')
```

Ok, where does that come from?

() indiate IN clause, but there is no IN.

SQL syntax says quality are = - that would be cid = 55

THen a number is not a string (no need for '55', it is 55).

Correct would be

```
cid = 55
```

Please, a one minute check of the documentation is sometimes ncice to learn a language. Helps to not throw random statements into a compiler hoping they are correct.